# write sqlite3 to csv using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, sqlite

I have a node application that needs to copy a sqlite3 table to a csv using a query.  I know in the command line you can do something like:

```
sqlite3 filename.sqlite
```

then:

```
.headers on
.mode csv
.output data.csv
    SELECT * FROM MyTable;
.quit
```

I don't see anything in the node-sqlite API and I'm struggling with copying to a Blob because the dataset is over a gigabyte.  What would be the preferred technique for handling this operation?  Am I able to call the sqlite3 command line from within Node?

One note is it's an electron application so I want to avoid external dependencies.